# Confused about instructions on course concerning initializing variables

Tags: c#

I am taking a C# course online, and it has me do activities where I copy and paste some of the code and I fill some in.

I am creating a program that can play a song using the `Console.Beep()` method.

And here are some of the instructions from the course, the underlined part is where i'm confused.

[image]

Comment: I'm note sure how I feel about a course that advocates mixing and matching naming conventions (case) in the same project/same class. Either way, can you seek clarification from your tutor?

Comment: If you're wondering why I suggest seeking clarification from your teacher, I can see many interpretations of how a single string could be used to initialize your class: 1. The string is the name for a song, and you need to look it up in a database. 2. The string is a serialized object (maybe a JSON string) which contains the data. 3. The string is a URL where the data can be obtained. 4. The string is a file which you need to load the song from. 5. The string is simply the name, and the class constructor should populate the notes based upon this name.

Comment: @john The course I am taking is rubbish for a number of reasons(bad habits, etc) but thats not the point. I unfortunately don't have a teacher/tutor to ask because the course I am taking doesn't have one(unless I pay 3x as much). Anyway there aren't any URLS or JSON strings in the lesson, I think its something much simpler but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: What is the question? How to set "notes" when only "Name" was provided?

Answer (score 3):

It really doesn't seem to be anything more than this:

```
class Song
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public LinkedList<Note> notes { get; private set; }
    public Song(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.notes = new LinkedList<Note>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought Properties required a get, set Like `public string Name { get; set;}` No? As shown, I would think the Name member would be a field.

Comment: @Mary - You're right. The requirements do indeed say "properties" in a couple of places.